# Android View with width in millimetre

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, measurement, fixed-width

In my project (Android) I need a view with exactly 5mm in width. Precision was much more important since it was using on a medical product.

I tried few ways,

```
val mm = 5
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
val mXDpi: Float = metrics.xdpi
val pixelMm:Float = mm * mXDpi / 25.4f
// val fiveMm:Float = Math.round(pixelMm * mXDpi)
// val fiveMm:Float = (pixelMm + 0.5f).toInt()
```

On some mobiles the results was acceptable. But when I was testing with

```
Xiaomi MiA1
```

width was only 4.9mm (expecting precise 5mm while measuring).

I find out the reason if am not wrong, it was

```
its screen was 1080 X 1798 pxls
physical width - 2.71 inches
1080 pxls / 2.71 -> 397.565 pxls
397.565 was the pixels per inch in width
397.565 / 25.4 will give the pixels per mm
```

I think this decimals on this value was making the inaccurate calculation.

```
Simply I need a view with exact 5mm in width.
```

make it simple,

```
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
val mXDpi: Float = metrics.xdpi
```

here,

```
mXDpi = 397.565
```

then I given width in pixel as 398. Still it is not exact 1inch (little less than 1inch) when I measured its width with scale with Xiaomi miA1. But Samsung devices are giving exact measurement.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the value of `pixelMm` when the app runs? How close is it to `78.2608...` (the exact value I'd expect to see)?

Comment: It was pixelMm  = 78.260826